# Is it possible to format the value with its base type?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have used the following method to convert the Date value,

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 3, 3);
string formattedText = string.Format("{0:MMM}", date);
```

So the resulted formatted value will be in string type. Is there any way to format the value with its base value type? i.e. DateTime value has to be formatted as DateTime

Comment: You can only format strings.

Comment: What do you want to get when you're 'format' DateTime to DateTime? It's illogically...

Answer (score 3):

### No.

Format concept *only* applies when you get *textual* (aka string) representation of a `DateTime` instance. You *can't* have a `Mar` as a `DateTime` for example, you can only have it as a `string`.

`DateTime` is a `struct` in .NET Framework which has a lot of fields and properties and it's [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks) based structure from January 1, 0001, midnight.

Comment: Well, OP could write a method that given a string, a lot of tryparse return the correct output... Couldn't he?

Comment: @Thomas Sure OP can parse `"Mar"` string to `DateTime` with `DateTime.ParseExact("Mar", "MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but _still_ `"Mar"` will be a `string`, not `DateTime`.